# Script tag not rendering synchronously

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, fetch, synchronous

this is the code im working with

```
<body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src = "http://localhost:3000/common_assets/navbar.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src = "http://localhost:3000//index.js"></script>

  <h1>MonkaHmm...</h1>

</body>
```

both the scripts render html and they both work the problem is the second script is always rendered last
so the MonkaHmm... comes in at the middle of the page.

this is the code thats in the second script tag

```
async function cardData(){
    var response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/Board_Members.json');
    var carddata =  await response.json();

    carddata.forEach(function(membercard){
      var member_cards = document.createElement("div");
      var code = `
        <div class="member_cards card-4">
          <img class = "img_member" src="http://localhost:3000/IMAGES/jonipic.jpg">
          <div class="description">
            <h5>${membercard.name}</h5>
            <h5>${membercard.title}</h5>
            ${membercard.description}
          </div>

        </div>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:3000/index.css">
`
      member_cards.innerHTML = code;
      document.body.appendChild(member_cards);
    });
}

cardData();
```

i have a feeling this is happening because of the fetch but its in an async/await function so i thought it would act synchronously but to be honest i have no clue. HELP my fellow pepega coders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `cardData()` it does invoke the async function and return a promise.  The browser doesn't wait for the response to continue rendering the page.

You could create the `member_cards` div or a placeholder and append it before you do your async calls and add your cards to it when you get the response.

Comment: O hmm i see whats happening now. Shit its so obvious. Thanks a bunch. So any suggestions on how to fix it. make the page wait till the script is done? or is using alternative to the fetch api the only way?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be as simple as changing `appendNode` to `insertBefore`

```
member_cards.innerHTML = code;
document.body.appendChild(member_cards);
```

to this

```
member_cards.innerHTML = code;
let h1 = document.body.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0];
document.body.insertBefore(member_cards, h1);
```

You should put in a check to make sure the getElementsByTagName call returns a value. If it doesn't you can either set a timeout or use your old appendChild call

Comment: epic stuff mate. epic. i did just that and its pooped it right before the monkahmm... im now looking for a way to place/render it after the first script. massive thanks

Comment: its not as easy as insertAfter()

Comment: so after about 5 minutes of tinkering i got it to render exactly as i wanted. thanks a bunch man literally saved me from hours of frustration. Cheers Mate. This pepega coder owes u